# Truck won’t start has no power to the dash or anything

Tags: electrical, chevrolet, silverado

I have an 04 Chevy Silverado with the 4.8L enigine and a manual transmission  and I am having electrical problems with the vehicle. One day I was coming to work and my clutch started going out I noticed it when I was parking when I got to work. It died on me while I had the clutch in as I was parking. Later that evening I was going to leave and I had no pressure in my clutch it was just plain petal. Note the truck would still start no problem. Well I called a mechanic I know who told me to start my truck in gear and just shift without the clutch so I could get it home. I told him Im on an incline and the only gear I have to go is reverse and he said that’s fine so I put my truck in reverse and went to start it and it jolted back then instantly killed everything. I have no power the the dash the radio or anything. Won’t turn over or anything. So I thought it was my starter solenoid shorted out so I bought a brand new battery and starter to see if that would cause it to have power to something and it still has no power. I popped the hood and when I took out the HDL-LOW relay fuse my dash would some what work. And when I went to start it I heard a really fast ticking noise coming out of the fuse box under my hood. I took a test light and texted all my fuses I could and they all had power and weren’t blown under the hood and under the dash and they were all fine. So does anyone have any idea on what I’m looking st here and how to diagnose the problem to getting my truck fixed?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!